# how to load images dynamically to image tag using asp.net from folder location

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an image tag on the page as shown below

```
<asp:Image ID="imgbadge" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="200px" />
```

and later based on the selection on the drop down box i need to assign the respective images to that image control.

I tried doing this

```
if (Session["BadgeType"].ToString() == "HAPPY BIRTHDAY")
        {
            imgbadge.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("images/HappyBirthdayBadge.png");
        }
        else
        {
            imgbadge.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("images/ServiceAnniversary.png");
        }
```

But i am not getting the image displayed on the page.I tried checking on the web but they are explaining about `using handlers`. where i am not getting complete details required.

Thanks,
Sai krishna

Comment: Debug it and check that you get exact path in Server.MapPath() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
img.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("images/ServiceAnniversary.png");;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `virtual path` of image and not the `physical path`, try this:-

```
imgbadge.ImageUrl = "~/images/HappyBirthdayBadge.png";
```

This should display your image properly.